# Call NSSharingService from FinderSync extension

Tags: swift, macos, nssharingservice

I am trying to send an email(open the default mail client application) from my FinderSync extension.

```
        let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingService.Name.composeEmail)
        if(service != nil)
        {
            service!.recipients = ["test@gmail.com"]
            service!.subject = "Test Mail"
           if service!.canPerform(withItems: ["Test Mail body"])
           {
                service!.perform(withItems: ["Test Mail body"])
           }
           else
           {
                  //fail for me
          }
        }
```

The same code executes from AppDelegate/ViewController while starting the main application but not working when calling from the extension.

Comment: What is the result of canPerform? I am afraid NSExtension instances are not allowed for NSSharingService (this is from dissasembly ShareKit.framework)

Comment: canPerform returns failure. I do not know how to check error message. I tried using delegate which also does not gets called

Comment: Read the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FinderSync is an `NSExtension` which is not allowed to use `NSSharingService`

```
/* @class SHKSharingService (ShareKit.framework) */  

-(char)canPerformWithItems:(NSArray *)items {
    if (([[SHKSharingService class] isShareKitPlugInService] || ([items count] > 0x1388)) {
    return NO;
}
```

`isShareKitPlugInService` is defined as

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary][@"NSExtension"]
```

Comment: thank you so much. Is there any other way to initiate email from Extension. I tried using "mailto" option. But there is no way to attach a file with "mailto"

Comment: I think it's better to open new question.

Comment: One idea might be to write xpc service (it might work)

Comment: I have done it by creating a separate application for opening mail application and call that new application from FinderSync using NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication